# What is a weight vectors weight really?

Tags: mathematical-physics, root-systems

What does a weight vector with weight $(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)$ actually mean?

Let $V$ be a $gl(n)$-module and I have that $v\in V$ is a weight vector if it is an eigenvector for all elements of the Cartan subalgebra, and so then let the basis of the Cartan subalgebra be $\{a_i^i:i=1,\cdots,n\}$ and we get $a_i^i v = \lambda_i v$ and we all the eigenvalues get put into this weight vector, yielding us the

$$(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)$$

Well what actually is this weight? How should I interpret it? What point is there to knowing this weight vectors weight?

Also while I am at it, what is a fundamental weight?

Comment: Also two textbook recommendations would be good if possible: One in terms of physical systems(although I have no physics background) and a second from an abstract point of view.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. It is precisely what you have written, so how can you ask what it is?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Sorry, my title should be (what is a vector weight really?)

Comment: The weight should be seen as an element in the dual of the Cartan subalgebra. So it should be seen as a map $\lambda: \mathfrak{h}\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $hv = \lambda(h)v$ for all $h\in\mathfrak{h}$.

Comment: For your added question: That is actually a pretty broad question, probably better answered once you have gotten some familiarity with how one works with these things. From the abstract point of view (I know nothing about the physics), Humphreys' book Introduction to Lie algebras and Representation theory is a pretty good start.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks for that recommendation. I'll read the relevant parts and try to self-answer the question here